# Locking an edge to a vertex in mxGraph

Tags: mxgraph

Given the javascript Hello World example (`mxgraph/javascript/examples/helloworld.html`):
If you click and drag the edge, it will move so that it is not connected to the vertices anymore. I want to modify `helloworld.html`, so that the edge cannot be decoupled from the vertices. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Place the following code before the try-finally block:

```
graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);
graph.setDisconnectOnMove(false);
```

This is explained in the [documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html).